# Sonarqube for Ruby code analysis

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

is there any plugins available for analyzing Ruby code inn sonarqube. I have downloaded Ruby plugin for sonarqube which has just very few rules like six. is there any other plugins for analyzing Ruby in sonarqube.

Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for the same thing for a while now.  It doesn't seem like there's any good support right now outside of [ruby-sonar-plugin](https://github.com/GoDaddy-Hosting/ruby-sonar-plugin).  SonarQube is a great tool and is awesome for managers to look into and it's a shame that the repo hasn't been updated for 2 years (at the time I'm writing this).

I know this isn't an answer, but it should provide more visibility on the question, at least.